# How many ways are there to place a set of chess pieces on the first row of chessboard?

Tags: additive-combinatorics

How many ways are there to place a set of chess pieces on the first row of chessboard when
the set contains 1 king, 1 queen, 2 identical rooks, 2 identical bishops and 2 identical knights.
With the following rules:

1. The bishops are placed on different colored squares
2. The king and queen are adjacent
3. There is a rook on either side of the king (not necessarily adjacent)

So far i've come up with 700 but i'm not sure if that answer is correct, would love to know what you guys think

Comment: "Fischer random chess" is a chess variant also known as chess960 for the number of positions.  Pieces are placed at random, except that the king has to be between the rooks and the bishops are on different squares.   Your question isn't quite the same, though, because you require the king and queen to be adjacent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer_random_chess.

Comment: Hey Michael, I know about chess 960, I want the answer for when the queen and king are adjacent.

Comment: OK!  I wasn't sure if you knew about it, and it seemed at least vaguely relevant.